# confused by python3 closure

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

this code

```
def gen(x):
    def f():
        return x

    return f

print(gen(1)())
```

works well.

but when i run this code,

```
def gen(x):
    def f():
        x += 1
        return x

    return f

print(gen(1)())
```

I got an error shows that

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

what happened to it?
and How to understand the closure of python3 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def gen(x):
    def f():
        nonlocal x # add this line
        x += 1
        return x

    return f

print(gen(1)())
```